# Using twitter bootstrap with Django forms

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to attach tooltip to my input field after it has been given to the browser. I am using the following, but it doesn't enter the second function wherein i have printed "Inside eventID javascript"

I am doing so because in my templates i am using {{ fields }} tag to display the input fields. If i specify the the html tag  the default value specified in the model does not get displayed.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function (){
   console.log("Test");
   $('#id_eventID').onfocus = function () {
    console.log("Inside eventDI javascript");
    $(this).tooltip({title:"helloooo!"});
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use bootstrap in Django I recommend using https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3 (V3) or https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit (V2).

Regarding the tooltipps: Why dont you use tooltip.js   http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips